# Rust: Modifying the referent of a reference with a function; does this contain UB?

Tags: rust, reference, undefined-behavior, unsafe

Recently, I wrote the following:

```
use std::ptr;

fn modify_mut_ret<T,R,F> (ptr: &mut T, f: F) -> R
  where F: FnOnce(T) -> (T,R)
{
   unsafe {
      let (t,r) = f(ptr::read(ptr));
      ptr::write(ptr,t);
      r
   }
}
```

This is a simple utility, so I expected it was in the standard library, but I couldn't find it (at least in `std::mem`). If we assume, for example, `T: Default`, we can safely implement this with an extra `drop` overhead:

```
use std::mem;

#[inline]
fn modify_mut_ret<T,R,F>(ptr: &mut T, f: F) -> R
  where F: FnOnce(T) -> (T,R),
        T: Default
{
    let mut t = T::default();
    mem::swap(ptr, &mut t);
    let (t,r) = f(t);
    *ptr = t;
    r
}
```

I don't think the first implementation contains any undefined behavior: we have no alignment issue, and we, with `ptr::write`, eliminate one of the two ownerships duplicated with `ptr::read`. However I'm anxious about the fact that `std` seemingly doesn't contain a function with this behavior. Have I got anything wrong or have I forgot something? Does the unsafe code above contain any UB?

Comment: In fact, `r` is *for* the return value. This is not ultimately necessary, since we can prepare `let mut r:R = R::default();` and let `f: impl FnOnce(T) -> T` replace the value of `r`. However it is bit of a trouble and I wanted to avoid it. Oops, you're gone? (Preceding comment disappeared)

Comment: Yeah, I realized it is probably for the return value so I deleted my comment.

Comment: You should not be worried that a function similar to `modify_mut_ret` is not in the standard library. Rust has a pretty small `std` by choice, and `std::mem` only provides basic building block functions for dealing with memory. `modify_mut_ret` looks like it has a pretty specific use case.

Comment: If `f` panics, `ptr`’s value gets dropped twice. I don’t think this function can exist.

Comment: @Ry- Oops. *Panic*. I knew it, if safe, was too primitive a utility to be absent from the standard library. So is this OK if I mark this unsafe and warn in the documentation that "Safety: the given closure should not panic"?

Comment: The [Ownership of the Returned Value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.read.html#ownership-of-the-returned-value) documented on `std::ptr::read` *seems* to indicate this is fine, though it doesn't mention anything about panicking and I have the same concerns as Ry. "Closure should not panic" is very hard for a user to guarantee.

Comment: Uh, ...I've forgotten even `Box::new` can panic. I just wanted to avoid extra drop, but it seems it's always better to pre-poop your pants...

Comment: This looks a lot like the [`replace_with`](https://crates.io/crates/replace_with) crate. In the docs there is a link to a RFC that tried to include it in std but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code contains only one instance of UB, which is because the function can return early. Let's take a closer look at it (I moved some things around to make it easier to take apart):

```rust
fn modify_mut_ret<T, R, F: FnOnce(T) -> (T, R)>(x: &mut T, f: F) -> R {
   unsafe {
      let old_val = ptr::read(x); // Copied from original value, two copies of the
                                  // same non-Copy object exist now
      let (t, r) = f(old_val); // Supplied one copy to the closure
      ptr::write(x, t); // Erased the second copy by writing without dropping it
      r
   }
}
```

If the closure runs fine, the outer function will progress as normal and the total number of copies of the old value of `x` is going to stay at just one copy, which will be owned by the closure, which it may or may not store for later in an `Rc<RefCell<...>>`/`Arc<RwLock<...>>` or a global variable.

If it panics, however, and the panic is caught by the code calling `modify_mut_ret` using `std::panic::catch_unwind`, there would be *two* copies of the old value of `x`, because the `ptr::write` wasn't reached yet but `ptr::read` already was.

What you need to do is handle the panicking by aborting the process:

```rust
use std::{ptr, panic::{catch_unwind, AssertUnwindSafe}};

fn modify_mut_ret<T, R, F>(x: &mut T, f: F) -> R
where F: FnOnce(T) -> (T, R) {
    unsafe {
        let old_val = ptr::read(x);
        let (t, r) = catch_unwind(AssertUnwindSafe(|| f(old_val)))
            .unwrap_or_else(|_| std::process::abort());
        ptr::write(x, t); // Erased the second copy by writing without dropping it
        r
    }
}
```

This way, panicking in the closure will never leave the function since it will catch the panic and abort the process immediately, before any other code can observe the duplicated value.

The `AssertUnwindSafe` is there because we have to ensure that we're not gonna observe logically invalid values created as a result of a panic, since we will always abort after a panic. See [`UnwindSafe`'s documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/trait.UnwindSafe.html) for more on that.